Android Keyboard crashing on static website
I'm a web beginner and I spent 1 month making a web project. It is for searching up staff emails in my school. However, when I asked my friends to try the website on their phone, the keyboard crashed (idk how to say but it just disappears) here is are links to screen recordings  https://streamable.com/mj1ael https://streamable.com/vxp5in.
here are some details of my website. It is static and hosted by github pages. I developed it with windows computer and checked mobile performance with iphone. One of my friends also used samsung phone to check the website. No errors occured. I used safari, edge and chrome and it all worked the same, so its not the browser's fault. On my iphone, chorme worked. On the android phones, it didnt.
im very sorry that since i dont rly know which part is causing this to happen, i will only put the code of the input box of which the error occurs:
<form id="form"> <input id="staffInput" type="text" autofocus placeholder="Enter staff name" autocomplete="off" class="form-control d-inline w-auto"> <button id="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary" style="background-color: #008fa0; border: none;">Submit</button> </form>

and heres javascript:
    event.preventDefault();     const inputName = document.getElementById('staffInput').value.trim().toLowerCase();```

SInce my website is static, im pretty sure you can check all its source code in developer tools, so here is my website link: https://singangle.github.io/staff-email-finder/ .  Please help me check why did this happen and how I should prevent it. Thank you so much !!!
